# Namespace, assembly, and inheritance hierarchy when including

Tags: c#, inheritance, namespaces, assemblies, class-hierarchy

Often when including namespaces or assemblies into my code, I often run into strange cases where a namespace is inherited from another, yet classes from the parent namespace are not available. For example, when using `List<>` or `Dictionary<>`, I use the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace. However, if I also want to use an `IEnumerator`, I also have to include the `System.Collections` namespace. Shouldn't `System.Collections` already be referenced by any member of `System.Collections.Generic`, as it is a child? Both namespaces also share the same assembly, mscorlib.dll.

Why is the parent namespace not included when the child is?

Comment: Because compiler is stupid. And has to be told what to include. Or what was the question?

Comment: @Sinatr That is the question, I just wonder why the compiler is so stupid as to not include a parent namespace

Comment: @OutlawLemur: By "stupid" I think you mean "complying with the language specification".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Shouldn't System.Collections already be referenced by any member of System.Collections.Generic, as it is a child?

No. There's no inheritance between namespaces. A `using` directive *only* imports types from that namespace - it doesn't import types from namespaces *starting* with the given namespace, or namespaces included within the given namespace's name.

For example, after:

```
using System.Collections;
```

... that doesn't let you use `List<T>` as a simple name for `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`, nor does it let you use `Guid` as a simple name for `System.Guid`.

The *only* exception to this is that if you're writing code within a namespace declaration of `X.Y.Z`, that implicitly imports namespaces `X.Y` and `X` (as well as `X.Y.Z`, of course). (In that example, `X.Y` is the *enclosing namespace* if `X.Y.Z`, but it's not an inheritance relationship.)

Comment: So there is no actual inheritance between namespaces, Msdn just uses the term in bad context? (See [`List<>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) for example)

Comment: @OutlawLemur: Where it is using the term incorrectly in that documentation? (Please quote exactly.)

Comment: Before the code examples or syntax in the inheritance hierarchy section

Comment: @OutlawLemur: That shows the inheritance of the *type* - so `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` inherits from `System.Object` for example. I see nothing that suggests one *namespace* inherits from another. (For example, type `Foo.Bar.Baz` could inherit from type `A.B.C`. That doesn't mean there's a relationship between the `Foo.Bar` and `A.B` namespaces.)

Comment: But `Foo.Bar.Baz` and `Foo.Bar` have no relationship?

Comment: @OutlawLemur: `Foo.Bar` is the namespace in which `Foo.Bar.Baz` is declared. It's still not an inheritance relationship though.

Comment: Ok... But in your example `X.Y.Z` where `X.Y.Z` imports `X.Y` and `X`... Why are many microsoft namespaces (`System.IO`, `System.Collections`) which have children not referenced in the child namespace?

Comment: @OutlawLemur: No, I think you misunderstood my answer. The point is that if you're *writing code* in namespace `X.Y.Z`, you can use types from `X` and `X.Y` without importing them explicitly. That has *no* impact on anyone using your type - it's only within your source code. Again, a namespace doesn't have "children" in an inheritance sense.

Comment: So there is a difference between C# and C++ or python haha... Thanks

Comment: @OutlawLemur: I don't know either C++ or Python well enough to say, I'm afraid.

Comment: Definitely a worthy question about clarifying the nature of namespace hierarchies in C++ vs C#, I've been struggling to articulate what the question would be but hopefully it'll appear in a new question shortly. He's using the language of inheritance but I think he may actually mean nesting, and you bring up good language too with the enclosing namespace term. Clarifying the X.Y.Z... namespace naming style and its relation to nesting namespaces I think is the key question. In the meanwhile I'll try to digest this [stuff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691136(v=vs.71).aspx)